# POST HTML form with Golang/Gin backend

Tags: html, forms, go, routes

I am trying to POST a simple HTML form to my backend, which uses Golang and [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin). Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="/login" method="post" name="loginForm">
          <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"></input>
          </div>
          <br /><br />
          <div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"></input>
          </div>
          <br /><br />
          <input type="submit"></input>
          <br /><br />
        </form>
```

And here is the route from my `main.go`:

```
r.POST("/login", func(c *gin.Context) {
        //What do I need to put here?
        formContent := c.PostForm("loginForm")

        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "status":  "posted to login",
            "message": "whoo",
            "form": formContent})
    })
```

When I submit the form, I receive the JSON response, but `formContent` is an empty string. I'm guessing I'm using the wrong method on `c`, but I'm not too experienced with Golang so not sure what to replace it with. I'm also not sure what additional capabilities Gin introduces here, as I'm essentially learning with trial and error from [an example project](https://github.com/Massad/gin-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md).

How do I properly access the form data on the backend?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: `<br /><br />` — In 1996 the CSS margin property was introduced. It has pretty good support these days.

Comment: `<input type="submit"></input>` — The end tag for the input element is forbidden in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your form:

> ```
> name="email"
> name="password"
> ```

Your server-side code:

> ```
> formContent := c.PostForm("loginForm")
> ```

You are looking for a field which does not exist.

```
emailValue := c.PostForm("email");
passwordValue := c.PostForm("password");
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!